# print the bubble sorted list from text file

Tags: c

I want to display the sorted list from a non-sorted list from a text file. sorting is partially done in the current program but I couldn't figure out the issue. I am totally lost on how to fix this issue and my lecturer also ignored my help so I would like to get help. The outcome of the current program is below.

````
void sort()
{
    struct sortL temp;
    int i=0, size, g;
    char bff;
    FILE * fp = fopen("donation.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nCan not open file.\n");
        main();
    }

    while (bff != EOF)
    {
        fscanf (fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %lf",&emo[i].IDd, &emo[i].supply, &emo[i].Scode, &emo[i].Cdonator, &emo[i].Nship, &emo[i].QuantityR);
        bff = fgetc(fp);
        i++;
    }

    size=i-1;

    for (i=0;i<size;++i){
        for (g=0;g<size - (i+1);g++){
            if (emo[g+1].QuantityR<emo[g].QuantityR);
            {
            temp=emo[g];
            emo[g]=emo[g+1];
            emo[g+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //fp = fopen("sortdonation.txt", "w");

    for (i=0;i<size+1;i++){
        //fprintf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %lf",&emo[i].IDd, &emo[i].supply, &emo[i].Scode, &emo[i].Cdonator, &emo[i].Nship, &emo[i].QuantityR);
        printf ("ID: %d Name of Supply: %s, Supply Code: %s, Donator: %s, Number of Shipment: %d, Number Donated (Million): %lf\n",
                emo[i].IDd, emo[i].supply, emo[i].Scode,emo[i].Cdonator, emo[i].Nship, emo[i].QuantityR);
    }
}```


OUTCOME:
ID: 4 Name of Supply: SurgicaMask, Supply Code: SM, Donator: China, Number of Shipment: 2, Number Donated (Million): 38.000000
ID: 3 Name of Supply: FaceMask, Supply Code: FM, Donator: China, Number of Shipment: 2, Number Donated (Million): 120.000000
ID: 2 Name of Supply: HandSanitizer, Supply Code: HS, Donator: USA, Number of Shipment: 1, Number Donated (Million): 3.500000
ID: 1 Name of Supply: ContaclessThermometer, Supply Code: CT, Donator: Japan, Number of Shipment: 1, Number Donated (Million): 1.200000
ID: 5 Name of Supply: OxygeonMask, Supply Code: OM, Donator: SaudiArabia, Number of Shipment: 2, Number Donated (Million): 9.000000
````

Comment: Consider looping `while (fscanf (fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %lf", ...) == 6) { i++; )` There is no need for `while (bff != EOF)`. You also fail to detect a *matching* or *input* failure due to not **checking the return** of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

The if check you done in sorting part has a semicolon right after if statement which kills if statement right there, it means the block you write for swapping works every time. You must get rid of the semicolon.

Also the `g < size - (i+1)` should be `g < size - i` otherwise the last element gets ignored.

After those fixes when I define your struct as

```
struct sortL {
    int IDd;
    char supply[32];
    char Scode[32];
    char Cdonator[32];
    int Nship;
    double QuantityR;
};
```

and change your

`fscanf (fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %lf",&emo[i].IDd, &emo[i].supply, &emo[i].Scode, &emo[i].Cdonator, &emo[i].Nship, &emo[i].QuantityR);`

line as

`fscanf (fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %lf",&emo[i].IDd, emo[i].supply, emo[i].Scode, emo[i].Cdonator, &emo[i].Nship, &emo[i].QuantityR);`

it worked fine for me.